# SQL Server dynamic procedure 2

Tags: sql, dynamic, sql-server-2008-r2, procedure

```
USE KronosNET22
GO

Create procedure eventossucursales4
    @id nvarchar(max),
    @dia nvarchar(max) 
as 
begin
    declare @sqlstring nvarchar(max)
    set @sqlstring = 'Select Code From ' +  @dia + ' WHERE idObject = ''' +  @id + ''' AND (CODE = ''TFHi2'' OR CODE = ''E603'')'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstring, @id,@dia
end
GO

Execute eventossucursales4 'E4211537-09CD-45F2-BB5F-F20F642DE676','ObjectSignal_2016_05_23 '
```

Error:

> Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 1
>   Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'E4211537'.

[image]

Can someone help me to figure it out why its showing a mistake in the declaration of the variable?

Comment: did you try adding a semicolon (`;`)

Comment: that does not solve the problem

Comment: try removing ,@id, @dia from the sp_executesql line. You are building a string, so no need to pass extra parameters to sp_executesql

Comment: You aren't actually creating a parameterized query - you're using string concatenation with variables.

Comment: removing ,@id, and ,@dia, dont change the log message

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate passing the parameters as someone commented.  If you want to make it work as is, you need to add the parameter list.  I was able to get it working this way.

```
alter procedure eventossucursales4
@id nvarchar(max),
@dia nvarchar(max) 
as begin
declare @sqlstring nvarchar(max)
declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500) = '@dia nvarchar(max), @id nvarchar(max)'

set @sqlstring = 'Select Code From ' +  @dia + ' WHERE idObject = ''' +  @id + ''' AND (CODE = ''TFHi2'' OR CODE = ''E603'')'
exec sp_executesql @sqlstring, @ParmDefinition, @id = @id, @dia = @dia
end
GO

Execute eventossucursales4 'E4211537-09CD-45F2-BB5F-F20F642DE676','ObjectSignal_2016_05_23 '
```

Comment: Joe C when i put the solution you gave me, the log still show me this message: 
Mens.102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 1
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'E4211537'.

Comment: im using sql2008 r2